# How do I get the effect of BlendMode.srcOver without making the rounded edges of Image to pointed ones?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, background-image, rounded-corners, colorfilter

I have a `Container()` that has a background image. This image already has rounded corners, so I haven't used any `borderRadius`. I want to add a color filter to this image with some opacity. So, I have used this :

```
Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("assets/images/signup_bg.png"),
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
            colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
              Color(0xFFEDDFD0).withOpacity(0.80),
              BlendMode.srcOver,
            )),
        color: Color(0xFFE5E5E5),
      ),
),
```

Now, if used `BlendMode.modulate`, then the corners of the image remain rounded but the color of the filter changes a bit even if I keep `Color(0xFFEDDFD0)` as the same. How do i achieve the effect of `BlenMode.srcOver` without making the rounded edges of the image turn into pointed edges.

PS: Also, in my case I can't change the `fit` property to anything other than `BoxFit.contain`.

Comment: you need `srcATop` (or `srcIn`), not `srcOver`

Comment: @pskink I tried using srcATop, srcIn and every other BlendMode constants mentioned [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/BlendMode-class.html). But, the effect of colorFilter I want only comes from srcOver but the edges get pointed.

Comment: so whats wrong with `srcATop`?

Comment: @pskink `srcATop` does keeps the image rounded but it fails to achieve the color effect like `srcOver`.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/KjvnSGN.png - the first image is `srcATop`, the second `srcOver`, the last one is original image - there is no difference between 1st and 2nd in the areas where image is not transparent